# Strange API Route error in laravel, One route working and another showing 404 for the same destination

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing a strange route error in laravel. One route is working fine and another is showing 404 not found error. How that can happen

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/check-balance', [\App\Http\Controllers\API::class, 'check_balance']); // Working
Route::post('/place-trade', [\App\Http\Controllers\API::class, 'check_balance']); // 404 not found error
```

And Controller is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;

class Users extends Controller
{
    public function check_balance()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Its working fine in localhost, not working on server only

Comment: Unless someone is doing magic, it'll be hard to help you. You have to provide additional information (actual test, content of controller, method, request...). The only thing we can say right now is something like "well, it should works".

Comment: Maybe something is going wrong in the check_balance method that throws a NotFoundHttpException?

Comment: @toyi, I have added whats in controller. I have reset the cache and all.. nothing worked..

Comment: Just confirming - it's a POST request, so you're accessing those routes using a form or a POST request, right?

Comment: @OfirBaruch then the first route also should not work... :( and yes I am accessing those using POST, and even I'll use GET, it will send method not allowed exception, not the 404 :( Helpless !!

Comment: Its working fine in localhost, not working on server only

Comment: Maybe something with the server configuration then. .htaccess / apache config is the same?

Comment: Could you run ```php artisan route:list``` on server to check if the route recognized?